# pyqt5 not showing window

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt5

I really hope someone can help me out on this one. 
Im trying to get started with using `pyqt5`, and have pretty much copied this code from a course that i am taking. the code seems to execute without any problems, but the window that i should be seeing is simply not appearing, what am I doing wrong? 
Im working on `ubuntu 18` by the way

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Page(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Page, self).__init__(parent)

    my_label = QLabel("This is my labet")
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    layout.addWidget(my_label)

    mainLayout = QGridLayout()
    mainLayout.addLayout(layout, 0, 1)

    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
    self.setWindowTitle("my first Qt app")

if __name__ == "__mongo__":
    import sys
    print("LOEREE")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Page()
window.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example there were some typos and at the end there was no line `sys.exit (app.exec _ ())` which starts the main loop of the application. From here begins the processing of events.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Page(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):             # __init__
        super(Page, self).__init__(parent)       # __init__

        my_label = QLabel("This is my labet")
        layout   = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(my_label)

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(layout, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("my first Qt app")

if __name__ == '__main__':                       # 
    import sys 
    print("LOEREE") 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Page()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())                         # !!!
```

[image]

Comment: ah yes, how silly thank you